# Wait for filter to complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter

is it possible to wait for a filter function to complete ?

I have this observable in Angular 6, where I do a filter. The filter takes some seconds, so it would be nice to do some function, wen te filter is complete. Is this possible ?

```
flSearch(input) {
    return this._plantCache.pipe( // Use downloaded JSON file
            map(
              (res: Array<Object>) => {
                return res.filter(item => {
                  return item['Fl'].indexOf(fl) !== -1;
                });
              },
              error => {
                this.loadingHide();
                return error;
              })
            );
}
```

other file

```
this._data.flSearch(data.value.searchPlant)
            .subscribe(items => {
              console.log(items);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your function return an observable https://angular.io/guide/observables

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

flSearch(input) {
    return new Observable ((observer) => {
      observer.next(this._plantCache.pipe( // Use downloaded JSON file
        map((res: Array<Object>) => {
          return res.filter(item => {
            return item['Fl'].indexOf(fl) !== -1;
          });
        }, error => {
          this.loadingHide();
          return error;
        })
      ));
    });
  }
```

**edit**: `observer.next()` is what you use to return your values, `observer.complete()` closes the observable so that it isn't using up memory after it has done its job. You will have to import rxjs to have access to the observable instance.

Comment: I think you are close, but it does not work. I get this error "[ts] Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.
this: this"

Comment: Could you try again, please ?

Comment: I edited the code to have a filter variable. that may help, but which line are you getting this error on? There aren't any functions that are taking in more than one variable

Comment: Also, I just updated the parenthesis/curly braces. I think I was missing one or two.

Comment: still get the same error "[ts] Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.
(parameter) res: Object[]". It must be because the map function only can have 2 arguments

Comment: So I changed the function one last time by wrapping everything in the observable. Notice that I didn't put the `observer.complete()` at the end because I think it would kill the observable before it had time to finish the filter function. My guess is that the function return the observable before the filter function is done (like what was happening before) but it is worth a shot. This is my last idea without changing whatever `_plantCache.pipe()` is to a service.